# Validate step inside input of type number

Tags: angularjs, regex

With the followinh HTML, it is not possible to validate the step:

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="number" name="test" min={{min}} max={{max}} step={{step}}>
<div class="error-popup" ng-if="myForm.test.$touched && myForm.test.$valid">
     <p>Invalid number</p>
</div>
</form>
```

For example if `$scope.min=3`, `$scope.max=9` and `$scope.step=0.3`, `myForm.test.$valid` remains true for values like 3.4 or 4.3 whereas it should not. So, I am thinking of using `ng-pattern`. Is it possible to construct such an `ng-pattern` that allows only `min+x*step` values or should I build a directive for that?

Comment: Use `ng-min`, `ng-max` and `ng-step`.

Comment: There is no difference

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `ng-model` for the input field. Please include that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form name="myForm">
            <input ng-model="yourValue" type="number" name="test" min={{min}} max={{max}} step={{step}}>
        </form>
        <h1>Validity: {{myForm.test.$valid}}</h1>
        <div class="error-popup" ng-if="myForm.test.$touched && myForm.test.$valid">
            <p>Invalid number</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.min = 3;
            $scope.max = 10;
            $scope.step = 2;
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```